# Unable to create AVD

Tags: android, adt

I download new android developer tools , create new project but I cannot not create android virtual device.

[image: 1]

But like image show I have only one target (Android 4.4 w) and when I choose it, I not have CPU (no system images installed for this target)

When I making application for target I set android 4.1.

Please help me.

Thanx

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse (if you do it from there)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Steps:
>
> 1: Eclipse > Window > Android SDK Manager > Android 4.4W(API 20)
>
> 2: There select, ARM EABI v7a System Image and Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image 
>
> 3: Scroll down to Extras , and select   Intel x86 Emmulator Accelator( HAXM Installer). This helps in speeding your emulator.
>
> 4. Click Install 3 packages in bottom-right.
>
> 5. Restart AVD with target = Android 4.4w, CPU/ABI = Intel x86 and check Use Host GPU(at bottom of AVD)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There are various things which can cause this:

1. You have not installed the system image. Open your SDK manager and ensure that you've  installed ARM EABI v7a System Image under the Android 4.2 section.
2. You need to restart Eclipse (or try it directly via the AVD tool)
3. You have spaces in your device name which can break the functionality
4. THe Eclipse Plugin is not up to date (if you start the AVD manager via Eclipse

In most cases it is System image which is missing. Give it a try.